# Redistribution ICPSR Data - Terms of Use

Tags: data-request, legal

On the website ([site](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/35017)), it says:

> **Access Notes**: These data are freely available.

At data download page ([download page](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/terms?path=ICPSR&study=35017&bundle=ascii&ds=1&dups=yes)), it has the term of use:

> **Redistribution of Data** You agree not to redistribute data or other materials without the written agreement of ICPSR, unless: 
>   (1) You serve as > the OFFICIAL or DESIGNATED REPRESENTATIVE at an ICPSR MEMBER
>   INSTITUTION and are assisting AUTHORIZED USERS with obtaining data, (2) or
>   You are collaborating with other AUTHORIZED USERS to analyze the data
>   for research or instructional purposes.

Question:

Can I put the downloaded data on my website?

Is putting data on personal website (on internet, open to public) considered redistribution?

Comment: offhand guess, probably...

Comment: sounds like you should make sure that you're collaborating with an 'AUTHORIZED USER'.

Comment: But is putting data on personal website (on internet, open to public) considered redistribution?